# When should I use Java's StringWriter?

Tags: java, string, stringwriter

What is a Java `StringWriter`, and when should I use it?

I have read the documentation and looked [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/stringwriter/java-stringwriter-example/), but I do not understand when I should use it.

Comment: Maybe this would be useful for other people to know.

Comment: All people can simply search for `StringWriter` javadoc.

Comment: What part of 'A character stream that collects its output in a string buffer, which can then be used to construct a string' don't you understand?

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers! They are all exceptionally useful! Especially, I would like to thank the people who answered for giving examples of usage that one cannot simply find in the documentation, such as @RossBille 's explanation of its usage in concatenation optimization, and Jaskey's explanation of its usage in printing stacktraces.

Comment: @MarkusWillson , please accept one of the answers if it answers your question and helps you. And next time, you should ask question with a more meaningful title with a narrow scope after you search some similar question on SO, so that nobody downvotes.

Answer (score 32):

It is a  specialized `Writer` that writes characters to a `StringBuffer`, and then we use method like `toString()` to get the string result.

When `StringWriter` is used is that you want to write to a string, but the API is expecting a `Writer` or a `Stream`. It is a compromised, you use `StringWriter` only when you have to, since `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` to write characters is much more natural and easier,which should be your first choice.

Here is two of a typical good case to use `StringWriter`

1.Converts the stack trace into `String`, so that we can log it easily.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();//create a StringWriter
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);//create a PrintWriter using this string writer instance
t.printStackTrace(pw);//print the stack trace to the print writer(it wraps the string writer sw)
String s=sw.toString(); // we can now have the stack trace as a string
```

2.Another case will be when we need to copy from an `InputStream` to chars on a `Writer` so that we can get  `String` later, using [Apache commons IOUtils#copy](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) :

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, encoding);//copy the stream into the StringWriter
String result = writer.toString();
```

Comment: A lot of your explanation was already covered in my answer

Comment: @RossBille , you give a good explaination but with a bad example in which we should not choose `StringWriter` actually. Besides, I don't think we should call it similar to `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder`, it is more like a adapter which deals with stream/writer cases , this should only be should when we have no other choices.

Comment: What is `t`? This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 7):

It is used to construct a string `char-by-char` or `string-by-string`.

It is similar to `StringBuilder` but uses a `StringBuffer` under the hood. This is preferable when you are working with an API that requires a stream or writer. If you don't have this requirement it should be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` (due to the synchronisation overhead of `StringBuffer`).

Of course this only makes sense if you realise that string concatenation (eg.

```
String s = "abc"+"def"; //... (especially when spread throughout a loop)`
```

is a slow operation (see [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html)).

small e.g.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
writer.write('t');
writer.write("his awesome");
String result = writer.toString();
System.out.println(result); //outputs this is awesome
```

A better example:

```
String[] strings = /* some array of strings*/
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
for(String s : strings){
    writer.write(s);
}    
String result = writer.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I will use StringBuffer/StringBuilder instead of StringWriter for your case.