# Why use StringWriter instead of StringBuffer?

Tags: java

I don't understand use of `StringWriter` in place of `StringBuffer`. Please help me to understand.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221292/when-should-i-use-javas-stringwriter

Comment: also http://www.coderanch.com/t/380184/java/java/wat-diff-stringbuffer-stringwriter

Comment: What would you do if you have an API that you want to call which accepts a `Writer`, and you want to create a string in memory?

Comment: I think ```new PrintWriter(new StringWriter())``` is useful. It has ```println()``` and ```printf()```.

Answer (score 4):

It is largely a matter of the APIs.

- `StringWriter` implements the `Writer` API; i.e. it can be used as a "sink" for capturing characters written to a character-based output stream.
- `StringBuilder` implements the `CharSequence` API.  This is more general than than `Writer` in that it also supports accessing characters that have already been written.  In addition, `StringBuilder` has methods for insertion and deletion at arbitrary positions.

It should also be noted that both `Writer` and `StringBuilder` implement the `Appendable` API which means that for some use-cases you can write a single method that can accept either a `StringWriter` or a `StringBuilder` for capturing text.

So ... which would you use?

- If you are calling an existing library method, you use which ever one is compatible with that method's API.  If both are compatible, you can use either.
- If you are designing an API method, you should probably use one of the respective superclasses / interfaces as the parameter (or result) type rather than hard-wiring `StringWriter` or `StringBuilder`.  That will make your method more general / more reusable.  Probably the most general is `Appendable` ... but is depends on what your method needs to do with the character sink, and predicted client requirements.